# How should i show monthly generated tickets through chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using rails 4, and I want to show monthly ticket generated through pie charts. Can anybody help?

Schema:

```
create_table "tickets", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "store_id"
t.integer  "vendor_id"
t.datetime "ticket_date"
t.datetime "deadline"
t.text     "description"
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
t.string   "ticket_no"
t.string   "vendor_name"
t.string   "user_id"
t.integer  "issue_id"
t.integer  "category_id"
t.boolean  "completed",   default: false
```

end

My `ticket.rb` contains:

```
def self.category_count(user,category)
 if user.vendor.nil?
 category.tickets.where('store_id = ?', user.store.id)
else
category.tickets.where('vendor_id = ?', user.vendor.id)
 end
end

def self.ticket_count(user,ticket)
 if user.vendor.nil?
  ticket.tickets.where('store_id = ?', user.store.id)
else
ticket.tickets.where('vendor_id = ?', user.vendor.id)
 end
end
```

view:
tickets:

index.html.erb file is:

```
<% data = {} %>
<% for category in Category.all %>
 <% data[:"#{category.name}"] = Ticket.category_count(current_user,category).count %>
 <% end %>
<%= pie_chart(data) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start by moving this into a view helper method such as:

```
def pie_chart_data(user)
  Hash[*Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, Ticket.category_count(user, c).count] }]
end
```

You could then call this in your view

```
<%= pie_chart(pie_chart_data(current_user)) %>
```

Comment: Still chart isn't coming up.

Comment: Well, is there an error? What's the implementation of `pie_chart`? You really haven't given us enough information to properly help you?

Comment: I uploaded rest of the code, I want to show monthly tickets generated on tickets.index.erb page.

Comment: You still haven't told us what specific problem you're running into. "the chart isn't coming up" isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: it is showing error: "undefined method `pie_chart_data' for #<#<Class:0x007f33758893e8>:0x007f3375899770>"

Comment: Where did you put `def pie_chart_data...end`? It's a view helper so it should be in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

Comment: i did the same as you told but, loading is showing on the tickets index page and after that showing blank.